# On Continuity and Discreteness

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, continuity

The *Point* has many definitions but when dealing with it purely geometrically, it seems to be defined as ***that which has no part***.

- ***When we put a point, for example, on a sheet of paper using a pencil, wouldn't the point have some amount radius to it on zooming*?**
  I have thought about the problem and perhaps one way of thinking about it is that as we zoom in, the point changes itself so that it decreases in size by the same factor as that of magnification, and thus, its definition holds. But this still doesn't explain how the point can have no part, i.e., no radius.
- Now, let's move to another topic, that of differential calculus. It is said that, geometrically, the derivative at a point is the slope of the tangent at that point and that the tangent only touches the curve at that point. ***But, if we once again zoom in to the point of contact, wouldn't it show an infinite number of points touching the tangent?***

***In general, how do we use a discrete quantity - the point - in something that is continuous - the curve?***

P.S. - I am a high schooler who just started learning calculus and would appreciate it if the solution, if possible, can be given in terms that can be understood by a high schooler

Comment: In real life it's impossible to construct the mathematical idea we have of a point. A point is a $0$ dimensional object, so when you "draw" it onto a sheet of paper you shouldn't be able to see anything (no matter how much you zoom in). This, of course, is quite inconvenient for anyone reading your graph, so we approximate it with a $2$-dimensional circle for convenience.

Comment: Well, how tangent lines work, you take the limit as $h$ approaches 0, where $h$ is the difference between some point you’re trying to find the slope of (call it point $x_1$), and another arbitrary point $x_1+h$. As $h \to 0$, this shouldn’t matter, it’s approaching a single spot on the curve. For probably a better explanation, see [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient)

Comment: Just a heads up: the oft-repeated characterisation of tangents as the line that touches the curve once is straight up false. Tangents often do intersect curves multiple times.

Comment: @Theo, wouldn’t that be a secant line?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins I guess technically they are? That doesn't mean they're not tangents. For example, take the tangent of $2x^3 - 3x^2$ at $x = 0$, which is the $x$-axis, and it intersects the curve at both $(0, 0)$ and at $(3/2, 0)$.

Comment: @Theo, I get you, yes

Comment: If you are beginning calculus you MUST learn the logical foundations of $\Bbb R$ and how that leads to its basic properties or you will become completely confused. BTW the name "real" numbers is merely a historical relic.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Is there any good resource to learn that?

Comment: The definition, etc.,of $\Bbb R$ is in many textbooks. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number. Or google Real Number System.

Answer (score 1):

In the physical world, the components of matter are not infinitely small. And measurements are  only  approximations,  ranges of numbers.

The use of $\Bbb R$ and other math can be justified as a model, a simulation.  Suppose we have an object $A$ and some process, denoted by $\to$, after which $A$ has changed into $B$. So we write $A\to B$. We may take  mathematical models $A^*$ and $\to^* $ and obtain a mathematical result $A^*\to^* X^*$. And $X^*$ should be a model of some $X$. Now we also have a model $B^*$ of $B$. How useful the model is, depends on how "close" $X$ is to $B$ and how "close" $X^*$ is to $B^*$.This of course depends on the context & the details.

Mathematical entities are  not defined by physics & chemistry.

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos .I had a computer glitch and when I returned, my A was edited but it looks exactly how I remembered it. No problem. I'm just curious.